# Python Access Pidgin Data Structure by Dbus

Tags: application-development, python, plugins, pidgin, dbus

I recentely started to program in Python and making a script/plugin for Pidgin,i need to access [PurpleConversationUiOps](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/struct__PurpleConversation.html) and use the  [has_focus](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/struct__PurpleConversationUiOps.html#a4efbcf4840b40df03d45826825902634) field,based in some examples in documentation of Pidgin i made this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import dbus, gobject
    from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

    def view(conv):
     if conv == 1: #if has focus
       print "Has Focus"

    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    bus.add_signal_receiver(view,
                    dbus_interface="im.pidgin.purple.PurpleConversationUiOps",
                    signal_name="HasFocus")
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

He gives no error but I don't receive any signal,so how can i access the has_focus field?

Comment: You might consider asking this over at StackOverflow.